# How to attach cucumber scenarios to Allure manual testcases with allure-cucumber7-jvm?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, allure

I'm researching the way how can we attach cucumber gherkin-scenarios to Allure manual testcases without loss of manual testcase data

Currently in the Internet there are multiple tutorials how to generate allure report but nothing about attaching automated scenarios to manual cases.
The most I have found is docs: https://allurereport.org/docs/cucumberjvm-reference/

Our stack is:

- allure-cucumber7-jvm,
- cucumber-java
- allure-junit5

we use gherkin to set tags for scenarios

To attach scenario to testcase I tried these things:

- matched cucumber feature name with folder where the Allure testcase is present
- matched cucumber scenario name with testcase name

Also I specified @allure.id of testcase in scenarios.

Eventually it ended up in completely removing manual testcases with scenarios. Manual steps and description disappeared.

Unfortunately, I can't show any code or screenshots..

Can you provide any example how to attach scenario to the testcase without removing initial testcase data?